# Java socket: Read does not return

Tags: java, sockets, server

It was supposed to be a 5-minutes test just to see whether it works as suggested. I wanted to create a stupidly simple HTTP "server" that does nothing but printing out what it gets (namely the HTTP requests).

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port); 
    try (Socket socket = server.accept()) {
        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        String received = input.readUTF();
        System.out.println("Received: \n" + received);
    }
}
```

But I came up with the following problem: When I start his program and then try http://localhost/ in Firefox, the stream gets stuck in the readUTF() method. It simply does not return.

I tried the same with socket channels and a buffer size of 128. There, it gets stuck after the third read (so anywhere between the 384th and 511th byte). This is the following code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    CharsetDecoder decoder = Charset.forName("UTF8").newDecoder();
        ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        serverSocketChannel.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port)); 
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferSize);
        buffer.clear();
        SocketChannel socketChannel = serverSocketChannel.accept(); 
        StringBuilder received = new StringBuilder();
        while (socketChannel.read(buffer) > 0) {
            buffer.position(0);
            received.append(decoder.decode(buffer).toString()); 
            buffer.clear();
        }
        System.out.println("Received: \n" + received.toString());
    }
```

They both show the same behaviour that the read method does not terminate. Do you have any idea, how to solve this and especially, what is the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: I did not see the code, which writes data to Socket. Can you post that part of code too?

Comment: That is done by the browser. As I mentioned above, this code listens on port 80 (HTTP server) and therefore, it connects with the browser when I request `http://localhost`. The connection works fine and in the second example, I can read 384 bytes (3x loop) until the read gets stuck. But the HTTP GET message is longer than 384 bytes. It seems that it doesn't recognize in the fourth loop stepthrough that the data is over now and it waits for more. But nevertheless, it should return and save the remaining data into the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

`DataInputStream` is used to read binary data. In this particular case it means that `readUTF()` method reads first the string length as two bytes and then reads as many bytes as the length received.

This stream is not usable for your needs, just simply read from `getInputStream()` or wrap it with `BufferedReader`.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the suggestion. But I guess, using `BufferedReader` instead of `DataInputStream` won't solve the actual problem I'm facing since in the version where I used socket channels I have the same problem. I'll also post the other solution.

Comment: The question is whether the server gets any data, i.e. whether the client sends anything. Otherwise, are you sure that in the second case `read()` doesn't really finish or just the loop doesn't finish? For the loop it's very probable as the client doesn't close the connection until it receives the response. Did you try running this in debugger?

Comment: Of course, I stepped through the code using the debugger and after 3 loops, it got stuck in the `read` method. So, I thought the reason must be related to anything with the browser-server communication. As far as I know, when the client writes something to the socket, the other end can read it completely and then it has the possibility to answer. But in this case, I even don't get the possibility to answer because it gets stuck.

Comment: Well, then the code works. But as you don't send any reasonable response, the browser waits for more data and doesn't drop the connection, and your code waits as well for more input which will never come. You need to send some real response as the next step.

Comment: But if I using this with a java-socket at the other side instead of the browser, it would probably work without response. I thought it works this way: Browser.write(some string); Server.read(some string); Server.write(resonse); Browser.read(response); So, shouldn't at least `read` terminate? Is there anything wrong? (Since I send no response to the browser, the browser won't load any page - that's clear so far, but currently, that's not important.)

Comment: `read()` doesn't terminate until the channel is closed from the other side. Which the browser doesn't do until it receives full response. And still then it can reuse the same connection for sending another request. So the code needs to understand the HTTP protocol in order to recognize the end of one request.

Comment: Okay. And how do I do it when I can't read the HTTP GET request? Since I don't know the length of the request, I'll never know how much to read.

Comment: In general you obviously cannot process something which you don't understand.